# Impact on social interactions after URL change

Tags: seo, google, web-development, search-engines, redirects

Every article URL on a website I work on will soon be changed.

301 redirects will be set up to ensure inbound links still arrive at the correct destination.

However, social interactions (Likes and Comments/Tweets/+1s) are attached to a specific URL - the previous one. When each URL changes all social interactions will be lost.

There doesn't seem to be much information out there regarding a way around this. The 301 redirects surely won't retain things like Facebook comments tied to a specific URL? What are my options for keeping these social interactions intact?